# How to get destination uid in sectionIndex menu in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I need to generate a sectionIndex with the following structure:

```
<div data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
  <dl class="sub-nav">
    <dd data-magellan-arrival="c123"><a href="#c123">Build with HTML</a></dd>
    <dd data-magellan-arrival="c124"><a href="#c124">Arrival 2</a></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

My problem is that I do not know how to set the correct value for the `data-magellan-arrival` property. **How can I retrieve the uid of the current item in the menu?**

My TypoScript currently looks like this:

```
lib.cb_foundation.magellan = HMENU
lib.cb_foundation.magellan {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        sectionIndex = 1
        sectionIndex.type = header
        sectionIndex.useColPos = 0
        wrap = <div data-magellan-expedition="fixed"><dl class="sub-nav"> | </dl></div>
        NO {
            allWrap = <dd data-magellan-arrival="c{field:uid}"> | </dd>
            allWrap.insertData = 1
        }
    }
    special = list
    special.value.data = page:uid
}
```

However, `{field:uid}` gives me the uid of the content element that uses this TypoScript, not the uid of the destination section element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{field:sectionIndex_uid}` instead of `{field:uid}`. There is a small hint at the bottom of [tsref](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Sectionindex/Index.html).